# How to install packages for python2 only?

Tags: python, kali-linux

Is there any ways install packages for **python2 only?**

I am using the latest Kali Linux version and I want to use some old scripts

At that moment of creating these scripts (Around years 2013-2015). The script was written in Python1 or Python2 and required me to install other packages such as "dns-python"

I did try to install these packages but I had some problems as the follow:

1. The script is already installed and automatically patched with latest python3 (not python2)
2. If I run python/ python2 to the script. It got error such as "ImportError: No module named 'dns'" (even I already installed this module successfully but it only patch to Python3)
3. If I run python3 to the script. It got some error such as the syntax is not correct (For example, the old python version using print command without "", or when you assign value, you will use "is", instead of using "==")

So the question is how to install packages for python2 only
I am not counting the way you roll back old Kali version

Comment: `python2 -m pip install packagename`

Comment: Not work bro :D